# dojo filteringSelect is very slow

Tags: ajax, select, dojo, filtering

In my project I am fetching cities using country selected.

Now I have about 8000 cities for 1 country, and because of that filteringSelect takes time to show it fast.

following are ajax functions I am using to fetch records and display it in my page.

```
function GetCities(){
  dojo.xhrPost({
    url: 'GetCitiesForCountry.action',
    load: getCityCallback,
    error: getCityError,
    content: {countryId: dijit.byId('cmbcountryid').value }
  });
}

function getCityCallback(data,ioArgs) {
  //alert(data);
  dijit.byId('cmbcityid').destroy();
  dojo.byId('td_city').innerHTML = data;
  dojo.parser.parse();

}
```

in above 'GetCitiesForCountry.action' will take countryId and will fetch all cities for that country and will create city combo and will return it.

in getCityCallback function I am placing returned combobox in its respective td using innerHTML.

This all works fine.

But when I click on dropdown button of fiteringSelect it takes about 5-6 seconds to show dropdown list.. I am not getting why?

Can anyone help me?

Is there any way to make it fast enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are yousing `<option>` to create the select or are you using an ItemFileReadStore (or some other store)?  8000 is a large number but on the same note 5-6 seconds sounds a little slow.

Comment: I am using <option> and not ItemFileReadStore.

Comment: That may be the problem. In any case I suggest to file a bug (http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` for a drop-down menu of about 6000 items.  The time taken for displaying/filtering various selections as the user types is very high.

Is there any fix or alternate option for making a typeable drop-down menu of large number of items (~6000) items.

Comment: By using 'pageSize=10' attribute I was able to improve performance on Firefox and other modern browsers.  Performance on IE6 and IE7 was still very bad.

Comment: I think problem seems to be with dojo itself..

thanks for you anwer.

amar4kintu

Comment: I would rather divide it into states and then cities. Problem solved and much more elegant in usage and its also make sense.